# sistema com 2 bancos de dados , retornando consultas vazias mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, query

Tenho um sistema onde tenho a base de usuários que é uma base unificada em um banco,e outra base a dos sistema.
Nas minhas páginas eu chamo eles assim:

```
<?php
include("conn_user.php");
include("conn_sys.php");
?>
```

Segue abaixo as conexões:

> include("conn_user.php");

```
$host1       = 'localhost';
$dbuser1     = 'root';
$dbpassword1 = '';
$dbname1     = 'cadastro';

$conn_user = @mysql_connect($host1, $dbuser1, $dbpassword1) or die ("Não foi possível conectar-se ao servidor MySQL");
$db1 = @mysql_select_db($dbname1) or die ("Não foi possível selecionar o banco de dados <b>$dbname1</b>");

$host2       = 'localhost';
$dbuser2     = 'root';
$dbpassword2 = '';
$dbname2     = 'eos';
```

> include("conn_sys.php");

```
$host2       = 'localhost';
$dbuser2     = 'root';
$dbpassword2 = '';
$dbname2     = 'eos';

$conn_user = @mysql_connect($host2, $dbuser2, $dbpassword2) or die ("Não foi possível conectar-se ao servidor MySQL");
$db2 = @mysql_select_db($dbname2) or die ("Não foi possível selecionar o banco de dados <b>$dbname2</b>");
```

Mais só que minhas consultas estão retornando vazias.
 Segue o exemplo de uma consulta:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="select" class="col-lg-4 control-label">SETOR:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
  <select type="text" class="form-control" name="setor" id="setor">
  <option selected value=''></option>
  <?php
  $setor = "SELECT * FROM setor ORDER BY setor_desc ASC";
    while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($setor)) {
    echo("<option value='".$dados['setor_id']."'>   ".$dados['setor_id']."   -   ".$dados['setor_desc']."   </option>");
    }
     ?>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

O que devo fazer para acertar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você está trabalhando com dois bancos é o obrigatório informar em qual deles quer realizar as operação(insert, update, delete select etc) do contrario o PHP vai pegar a última conexão aberta. Para resolver isso informe qual banco/conexão deseja usar em `mysql_query()`.

Note que a conexão é sempre o segundo argumento ou seja é o inverso do mysqli.

Assinatura da função:

> mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )

```
$result = mysql_query('select ... from ...', $banco1);
$result2 = mysql_query('select ... from ...', $banco2);
```

Vale lembrar essas funções já foram removidas do PHP7 então atualize seu código com o mysqli ou PDO.

**Relacionado:**

[Manual - mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Oi perfeito,era isso mesmo. Sobre o PHP7 já estou estudando o PDO. Ainda sim,Obrigado pela ajuda.